# How to connect to a ssh server through several ssh servers with Bash script

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to connect to several ssh server (like proxy) with Bash script like this:

```
ssh server 1 -> ssh server 2 -> ssh server 3
```

In this example I just have access to `server 2` just via `server 1`. Also I just have access to `server 3` just via `server 2`.

Actually I want to implement this to have easy access on `server 3` via just one command (Bash script).

Comment: This might help: [Is it possible to combine these two ssh commands into one?](https://superuser.com/q/784052/340330)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This action would be handled by `ssh config` and `expect`:

**ssh config (my.conf):**

```
Host Server1
    User root
    HostName 192.168.100.10
Host Server2
    User root
    HostName 192.168.100.5
Host Server3
    User root
    HostName 192.168.100.2
    ProxyJump Server1, Server2
```

**expect code (server3.sh):**

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn ssh -F my.conf Server3
expect "password"
send "PASSWORD-OF-SERVER-1\r"
expect "password"
send "PASSWORD-OF-SERVER-2\r"
expect "password"
send "PASSWORD-OF-SERVER-3\r"
expect "$"
interact
EOF
```

Finally try it:

```
$ server3.sh
```